# Are there infinite sequences not reproducible by finite algorithms?

Tags: logic, soft-question, algorithms, computer-science

Let me know if this is a repeat question.  I was thinking that sequence of integers we deal with (e.g., the digits of $\pi$, the prime numbers, the Fibonacci numbers, pseudorandom numbers) seem to be reproducible by a finite algorithm.

Are there infinite sequences of integers which  are not reproducible by a finite algorithm? If so, do we know much about what these sequences "look like"?  E.g., what is their cardinality?

Also, is there a name for a number whose decimal expansion is such a sequence? Do we know much about these numbers?

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of Kolmogorov complexity?

Comment: This might be of your interest http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number

Comment: Since there are only countably many finite algorithms and uncountably many sequences of integers, there must necessarily be many sequences that cannot be produced by any finite algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the references and easy explanation!

Comment: I have a copy of _The Annotated Turing_ by Petzold, which talks about this and which I recommend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are uncountably many such real numbers.

Any algorithm can be described as a sequence of 0's and 1's that encode its operations.  Thus, we can identify any algorithm with a natural number, so it makes sense to speak of the $k^{th}$ algorithm.

Let $\alpha$ be the real number such that the $k^{th}$ digit is 1 if the $k^{th}$ algorithm halts after a finite number of steps when run with an empty string as it's input and 0 otherwise.  This is basically the halting problem, so no algorithm can enumerate the digits of this real number.

To see that uncountably many such real numbers exist, note that the number of algorithms described by finite strings is countable.

Comment: Uncountably many such sequences, not numbers.

Comment: Well, I meant real numbers which is equivalent since I'm only considering at binary digits.

Comment: Since there was no reference to real numbers anywhere in the quesiton, "such numbers" indicates "numbers that we were previously discussing." So just say "uncountably many real numbers."

Comment: The question mentions $\pi$.  Anyway, I already clarified it.

Comment: No, you've buried the clarification in the answer. When reading the sentence, the reader has no idea what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Look up "[recursive set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_set)", also "[Chaitin's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant)".

Answer (score 0):

If you want a concrete example that in theory should be computable but not by any fixed finite length algorithm, consider the "busy beaver" function $B(n)$. This is the maximum number of steps a computer program of size $n$ can run on empty input and terminate without running forever. It is possible to compute $B(n)$ for small $n$, and some believe that longer and longer computer programs can compute $B(n)$ for arbitrarily large $n$ (where each program has a limit on $n$ that it can compute $B(n)$ for), but there is no one fixed finite length program that can compute $B(n)$ for all $n$.

Comment: "…and some believe that longer and longer computer programs can compute $B(n)$ for arbitrarily large $n$…" Here's to hoping that there's some simple-ish program that works up to n = a million.

Comment: You have to be more specific, specifying the particular language the computer program is to be written in.  The original formulation is in terms of Turing machines.

For any particular $N$, since $B(1), B(2), \ldots, B(N)$ is a particular finite sequence of integers, **of course** there is a program that computes $B(n)$ for $1 \le n \le N$.  The program contains that sequence as a constant, and just outputs the $n$'th member.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I meant something more subtle, and it doesn't depend on the language (although changing the language changes the value of $B(n)$, but let's just consider the language fixed). Current programs that compute $B(n)$ PROVE that the value is correct, without knowing it ahead of time so that it can be hard-coded as a constant. That's what I mean by some believe that sufficiently large computer programs can PROVE the value of $B(n)$ for any $n$ if the program is sufficiently long. Of course given any finite sequence we can write a program that prints out values of that sequence.

Comment: That's not true then, if PROVE refers to some particular consistent formal system $S$.  If you know the value of $B(n)$, then you can check whether a program of size $n$ halts, by checking that it takes more than $B(n)$ steps without halting.  Now consider a program $P$ that looks for an inconsistency in system $S$ by iterating over natural numbers and checking whether each is the Godel number of a proof in $S$ of $0=1$. ...

Comment: ... This program never halts, but there is no proof in $S$ that it never halts (because Godel shows a consistent formal system can't prove it is consistent), and so there is no proof in $S$ of the value of $B(n)$.  Since there is no such proof, there is no program to PROVE the value of $B(n)$.